# Add unity application to React Native

Tags: android, react-native, unity-game-engine, expo

I have created an AR application in unity. Now I need to add that application to my react native mobile application. The react native app was build using expo. I need to open the unity app when I click a button in the react native application. I don't need to share data among react native and unity applications. Just need to open the unity application smoothly like the user shouldn't feel that when he press the button he didn't redirect to another separate application.

Comment: Can't do it in the managed workflow- you can eject and use something like react-native-unity-view

Comment: @Abe So with the expo can't I connect the unity app?